# How to Print the html output into Pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

[Here is my output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2al6U.png)

Here is my code

> let input = document.querySelector('input');
>         var textarea = document.getElementsByClassName('area')[0];
>         var txtreplace = document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0];
>          window.addEventListener('load',
>             function () {
>                 input.addEventListener('change', () => {
>                     let files = input.files;
>                    if (files.length == 0) return;
>                    const file = files[0];
>                     let reader = new FileReader();
>                    const fruits = [];      
>                   reader.onload = (e) => {
>                         const file = e.target.result;
>                         const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
>                         //console.log(lines.length);
>                         textarea.value = lines.join('\n');
>                         lines.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
>                             //console.log(arrayItem.replace("\u001bE", "**"));
>                             var arr1 = arrayItem.replace("\u001bE", "");
>                             var arr2 = arr1.replace("\u001bF", "**");
>                            
>                             fruits.push(arr2);
>                  
>                         });
>                         console.log(fruits.length);
>                         if (parseInt(fruits.length) > 0) {
>                             console.log(fruits);
>                             txtreplace.innerHTML = fruits;
>                         }
>                   
>                     };
>
> ```
>                 reader.onerror = (e) => alert(e.target.error.name);
>
>                 reader.readAsText(file);
>
>             });
>         }, false);
>       
>     function printDiv() {
>         var divContents = document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML;
>         var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
>         a.document.write('<html>');
>         a.document.write('<body > <h1>Print PDF <br>');
>         a.document.write(divContents);
>         a.document.write('</body></html>');
>         a.document.close();
>         a.print();
>     }
>
> </script> </body>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF.
It's js library allow you to build pdf using Javascript.

Otherwise have some solutions to convert html page to pdf ( https://www.html2pdf.co.uk/ ), but I don't think it's what you are looking for.

Exemple of code using JSPDF :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>


var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');

doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Hope it will helps you ;)

Comment: thanks for you response but here i want to print my text content into pdf file

Comment: I think jspdf can helps you, I shared an exemple to write text into a pdf and then export it

Comment: here my problem is every time i have to upload text file in that text file some string replacing happen automatically in code then that that text file after changes it will download by clicking Download button

Comment: Okay, so I really think jspdf can do it. You read the `text file` => you do the `remplacement` => you get a `text` you want to export as pdf =>you `click the button` => it `generate` your `pdf  filled with the your `text` then it export the pdf ` using jspdf